# Grepping non printable characters by Cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, grep, non-printable

Grepping non printable characters doesn't seem to work for carriage return (control key ^M).

```
usr@R923047 ~
$ head -3 test.ctl
row 1
row 2
row 3
usr@R923047 ~
$ head -3 test.ctl | cat -nv
     1  row 1^M
     2  row 2^M
     3  row 3
usr@R923047 ~
$ head -3 test.ctl | grep '[^[:print:]]'

usr@R923047 ~
$ head -3 test.ctl | grep '[[:cntrl:]]'

usr@R923047 ~
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the `grep` man-page, you can specify `-U` or `--binary` to:

> Treat  the  file(s) as binary.  By default, under MS-DOS and MS-Windows, `grep` guesses the file
>   type by looking at the contents of the first 32KB read from the file.   If  `grep`  decides  the
>   file  is  a  text  file,  it strips the CR characters from the original file contents (to make
>   regular expressions with `^` and `$` work correctly).  Specifying  `-U`  overrules  this  guesswork,
>   causing  all  files to be read and passed to the matching mechanism verbatim; if the file is a
>   text file with CR/LF pairs at the end of each line, this will cause some  regular  expressions
>   to fail.  This option has no effect on platforms other than MS-DOS and MS-Windows.

So:

```
$ head -3 test.ctl
row 1
row 2
row 3
$ head -3 test.ctl | cat -nv
     1  row 1^M
     2  row 2^M
     3  row 3
$ head -3 test.ctl | grep '[^[:print:]]'

$ head -3 test.ctl | grep '[[:cntrl:]]'

$ head -3 test.ctl | grep -U '[^[:print:]]'
row 1
row 2

$ head -3 test.ctl | grep -U '[[:cntrl:]]'
row 1
row 2
```